# Trying make a status based on a boolean value to change an icon to tick in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to make a status based on a boolean value to change an icon to tick
if it is true and do nothing if its false. Tried to make logic but something not
working well. Please help.

```
class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar( {Key? key, required this.title, required this.status}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;
  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {




return Row(
  children: [
    Text('${widget.title}'),

     IconButton(
      icon: true
          ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border)
          : Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
            ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          // Here we changing the icon.
          var status = !true;
        });
      }),
  ],
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {      
bool _favoriteStatus = widget.status;
                        
         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('${widget.title}'),
                IconButton(
                    icon: _favoriteStatus ? const Icon(Icons.favorite) : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _favoriteStatus = !_favoriteStatus;
                      });
                    }),
              ],
            );
          }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the status in stateful widget, you can use it as `widget.status`  and check using ternary operator `? :`

Example

```
class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar( {Key? key, required this.title, required this.status}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;
  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {  

late bool status;

@override
void initState() {
  status = widget.status;
  super.initState();
}   
                
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('${widget.title}'),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(status ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                status = !status;
              });
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar( {Key? key, required this.title, required this.status}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;
  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {

bool initialStatus=widget.status;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {




return Row(
  children: [
    Text('${widget.title}'),

     IconButton(
      icon: initialStatus
          ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border)
          : Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
            ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          // Here we changing the icon.
           initialStatus = !initialStatus;
        });
      }),
  ],
);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `status` in your state widget and toggle the boolean when clicking on the icon.

Also, you can access the fields of the widget from its state through the `widget` property of the state.

```dart
class OrderStatusBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderStatusBar({Key? key, required this.title, required this.status}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final bool status;

  @override
  State<OrderStatusBar> createState() => _OrderStatusBarState();
}

class _OrderStatusBarState extends State<OrderStatusBar> {
  late bool status;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    status = widget.status; // you will need to implement the initState() function as the `widget`
                            // property cannot be accessed during the instance initialization
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Text(widget.title),
      IconButton(
          icon: status ? const Icon(Icons.favorite_border) : const Icon(Icons.favorite),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              status = !status; // here we toggle the status field of the state widget
            });
          })
    ]);
  }
}
```